# Why does this code seem to exhibit a bug?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, compiler-bug

I've got a `CanExecute` for a WPF command that seems to work differently depending on how explicit I am with the compiler; the problem is, I wouldn't expect to have to be explicit.

```
private bool CanRemoveField()
{
    return SelectedField != null &&
        Context.Item.Id == 0
        ? _fieldsByFieldModel.ContainsKey(SelectedField)
        : !_hasAnyCosts;
}
```

The above code, when queried for an Item where `Id != 0` holds true, the button is enabled **despite** `SelectedField` being `null`, so I'd expect the conditional to short out and return `false`.

The code tweaked slightly:

```
private bool CanRemoveField()
{
    return SelectedField != null &&
        (Context.Item.Id == 0
        ? _fieldsByFieldModel.ContainsKey(SelectedField)
        : !_hasAnyCosts);
}
```

I've introduced some parentheses around the ternary if, and this now exhibits the desired behaviour of disabling the button when no field is selected.

Given the fact it's a ternary if, I'd have expected the behaviour I wanted to be possible without the need for parentheses as it should just be seen as one statement, no?

Comment: Keep in mind :[It's Always Your Fault](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The results you're seeing make sense, since [the `&&` logical-and operator has a higher precedence than the `? :` conditional expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

So your first code snippet is essentially:

```
return (SelectedField != null && Context.Item.Id == 0)
    ? _fieldsByFieldModel.ContainsKey(SelectedField)
    : !_hasAnyCosts;
```

Comment: Thanks! Operator precedence makes sense, I guess I just assumed it would treat the ternary if as a group.

Answer (score 8):

Because of operator precedence, your first example is equivalent to:

```
private bool CanRemoveField()
  {
    return (SelectedField != null &&
        Context.Item.Id == 0)
        ? _fieldsByFieldModel.ContainsKey(SelectedField)
        : !_hasAnyCosts;
  }
```